# Highlight word in TListView Delphi 7

Tags: delphi-7

I'm trying to highlight a word from TListView but I can't make it work. My first attempt is to highlight the first letter of each row but won't work. TListView won't display anything. Here is my code:

```
procedure TfrmMain.lvMainDrawItem(Sender: TCustomListView; Item: TListItem; Rect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
var
  r : TRect;
  c : TCanvas;
begin
  r := Item.DisplayRect(drBounds);
  c := Sender.Canvas;

  c.Brush.Color := clWindow;
  c.Font.Color := clWindowText;
  c.TextRect(r, 1, 1, 'a');
end;
```

I based my code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70849535/how-to-highlight-apples-and-oranges-with-a-custom-color-in-tlistview) but it is written in XE10.4. I'm using delphi 7. How can I highlight word/first letter of each row in TListView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are drawing outside of the item's bounding rectangle, that is why you don't see anything. The X,Y coordinates you specify to `TextRect()` are relative to the top/left corner of the ListView's client area, but are clipped by the specified `TRect`.

Try this instead:

```
c.TextRect(r, r.Left+1, r.Top+1, 'a');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my working code:

set and populate list view

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin

  ListView1.Clear;
  ListView1.ViewStyle := vsReport;
  ListView1.RowSelect := True; 
  
  ListView1.Items.Add.Caption := 'banana';
  ListView1.Items.Add.Caption := 'apple and banana';
  ListView1.Items.Add.Caption := 'orange apple and banana';
  ListView1.Items.Add.Caption := 'banana and orange';
  ListView1.Items.Add.Caption := 'banana orange and apple';

  ListView1.Items.Add.Caption := 'appleXandXbanana';
  ListView1.Items.Add.Caption := 'orangeXappleXand banana';
  ListView1.Items.Add.Caption := 'bananaXandXorange';
  ListView1.Items.Add.Caption := 'bananaXorangeXandXapple';
end;
```

painting

```
procedure TForm1.ListView1DrawItem(Sender: TCustomListView;Item: TListItem; Rect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
var
  r : TRect;
  c : TCanvas;
  sText : string;
  sTemp : string;
  nPos : Integer;
  nLen : Integer;
  lv : TListView;
begin
  if item = nil then
  begin
    Exit;
  end;

  r := Item.DisplayRect(drBounds);
  c := Sender.Canvas;
  lv := TListView(Sender);

//  fKeyword := 'apple';
  sText := Item.Caption;
  nLen := Length(fKeyword);
  nPos := AnsiPos(fKeyword, sText);

  // first part : before match
  sTemp := Copy(sText, 1, nPos - 1);
  if sTemp <> '' then
  begin
    c.Brush.Color := clWindow;
    c.Font.Color := clWindowText;
    c.TextRect(r, r.Left, r.Top, sTemp);
    Inc(r.Left, c.TextWidth(sTemp));
  end;


  // second part: match
  sTemp := Copy(sText, nPos, nLen);
  if (nPos > 0) and (sTemp <> '') then
  begin
    c.Brush.Color := clRed;
    c.Font.Color := clBlue;
    c.TextRect(r, r.Left + 1, r.Top, sTemp);
    Inc(r.Left, c.TextWidth(sTemp));
  end;

  // third part : after match
  if nPos = 0 then
  begin
    sTemp := sText;
  end
  else
  begin
    sTemp := Copy(sText, nPos + nLen, Length(sText) - nPos - nLen + 1);
  end;

  c.Brush.Color := clWindow;
  c.Font.Color := clWindowText;
  c.TextRect(r, r.Left + 1, r.Top, sTemp);
  Inc(r.Left, c.TextWidth(sTemp));


  if odFocused in State then
  begin
    lv.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsSolid;
    lv.Canvas.Brush.Color := clBlack;
    lv.Canvas.Font.Color := clWhite;
    DrawFocusRect(lv.Canvas.Handle, Rect);
  end;
end;
```